# I am using sed -i ina while loop. But while replacing string it adds new line after matching

Tags: sed

I have a file that has some text like this:

```
AFG20-ENV284E2
AFG21-003
AFG22-189
PAK20-10092
PAK20-11742
PAK20-13467
PAK20-2903
```

I wanted to change them to

```
AFG20-ENV284E2|09-27-2020
AFG21-003|01-01-2021
AFG22-189|01-14-2022
PAK20-10092|09-03-2020
PAK20-11742|10-03-2020
PAK20-13467|11-05-2020
PAK20-2903|02-12-2020
```

I used sed in a while loop like this:

```
while read oldnames newnames; do sed -i "s/$oldnames/$newnames/g" edited.mcc.tre; done <replace-oldnames.txt
```

this works very well but it adds a new line after every matching string. How can I avoid the code to not add a newline after matching ??

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, on what basis your output is coming? What is the Logic of getting it please explain it more in your question, thank you.

Comment: its a phylogenetic tree file..

Comment: Basically I want to ask how `AFG20-ENV284E2` has become `AFG20-ENV284E2|09-27-2020` in your expected output?

Comment: oh ok.. actually I have added the dates to titles. I had that information in my metadata..
I made a file names as "replace-oldnames.txt" with two columns one with current name "AFG20-ENV284E2"  and second column with name to be replaced with "AFG20-ENV284E2|09-27-2020"

Comment: Ok then please post the other file also from where you are pulling data and you want to get required output.

Comment: Your code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is working perfectly.
See below

replace-oldnames.txt

```
AFG20-ENV284E2 AFG20-ENV284E2|09-27-2020
AFG21-003 AFG21-003|01-01-2021
AFG22-189 AFG22-189|01-14-2022
PAK20-10092 PAK20-10092|09-03-2020
PAK20-11742 PAK20-11742|10-03-2020
PAK20-13467 PAK20-13467|11-05-2020
PAK20-2903 PAK20-2903|02-12-2020
```

edited.mcc.tre

```
AFG20-ENV284E2
AFG21-003
AFG22-189
PAK20-10092
PAK20-11742
PAK20-13467
PAK20-2903
```

```
while read oldnames newnames; do sed -i "s/$oldnames/$newnames/g" edited.mcc.tre; done <replace-oldnames.txt
```

```
Output: cat edited.mcc.tre
AFG20-ENV284E2|09-27-2020
AFG21-003|01-01-2021
AFG22-189|01-14-2022
PAK20-10092|09-03-2020
PAK20-11742|10-03-2020
PAK20-13467|11-05-2020
PAK20-2903|02-12-2020
```